# Time selection in a Calendar

Tags: primefaces

I am trying to get a date from a Calendar. If I use the displayed code, it works, but as soon as I change the pattern to="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", the listener "send" is not called.

```
<h:form id="customerManagementForm">
    <p:calendar value="#{dashboardEstatico1Bean.fecha}" id="calendarEsp" 
        locale="es_ES" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" 
        minHour="9" maxHour="18" stepHour="1" stepMinute="1" 
        showOn="button" mode="inline">
        <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{dashboardEstatico1Bean.send}"/>
    </p:calendar>
</h:form>
```

Any idea?

Comment: I have discovered that if I remove mode="inline" it works.

Comment: It's bug on PrimeFaces.

Take a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23036356/bug-in-primefaces-calendar-timepicker/23037478